# Errno socket error in python

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, urllib

i wrote this code :

```
import random
import sys
import urllib
openfile = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
c = random.choice(openfile)
i = 0
while i < 5:
 i=i+1
 c = random.choice(openfile)
 proxies = {'http': c}
 opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies).open("http://whatismyip.com.au/").read()
```

::: I put 3 proxy in a txt file . :

```
http://211.161.159.74:8080
http://119.70.40.101:8080
http://124.42.10.119:8080
```

but when execute it i get this error :

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] (10054, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

what am i going to do ? 
please help me .

Comment: Have you performed the tests indicated here?: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957018.aspx

Comment: you will contribute to all us indicating how you solved the problem or indirectly by voting up the answer that gave you the clue. This will motivate us for answering your future questions.

Answer (score 2):

The first proxy you list is giving my telnet an ECONNRESET too. What makes you think these are valid proxies?
Incidentally, if you are trying to find out their DNS names, they don't have any.

```
$ dig -x  211.161.159.74 
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```